# Отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в программировании. Необходимо реализовать операции сложения, вычитания и тп. В main возникла проблема при объявлении объекта n1 " для класса Calculate не существует конструктор по умолчанию". Подскажите пожалуйста , где ошибка и что я сделал не так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculate {
private:
    int  x, y;




public:

    Calculate(int a, int b) {
        int x = a;
        int y = b;

    }


    void setNum() {

        cout << " Enter x:";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y: ";
        cin >> y;


    }
    void showNum() {

        cout << " x= " << x << endl;
        cout << "y= " << y << endl;


    }
    void sum(int x, int y) {
        int sum = x + y;
        cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    }
    void sub(int x, int y) {
        int sub = x - y;
        cout << "Sub = " << sub << endl;

    }
    void mul(int x, int y) {
        int mul = x*y;
        cout << "Mul = " << mul << endl;
    }
    void div(int x, int y) {


        if (y == 0) {
            cout << "Division by zero" << endl;

        }
        else {
            int div = x / y;
            cout << "Div = " << div << endl;
        }
    }

};


int main() {


    int a, b;

    Calculate n1;

    n1.sum(a,b);
    n1.sub(a,b);
    n1.mul(a,b);
    n1.div(a,b);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А чего ты ожидал - у тебя объявлено

```
Calculate n1;
```

Когда ты сам в классе прописал, что у тебя только один конструктор и он соответствует

```
Calculate n1(10, 20)
```

В классе надо указать еще один конструктор без параметров (конструктор по умолчанию)

```
Calculate() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
```

Когда ты в классе в явном виде указываешь конструкторы, они в неявном виде уже не предусматриваются.

Поэтому у тебя должно быть следующее:

```
class Calculate { 
    private: 
        int x, y;

    public:

        Calculate() {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        Calculate(int a, int b) {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

    /* тут твои методы */
};
```

**Ну и вторая ОФИГЕННАЯ ошибка:**

Ты в конструкторе присваиваешь значения x, y, которые являются локальными и после завершения работы конструктора сдохнут

```
        Calculate(int a, int b) {
            int x = a;
            int y = b;
        }
```

**int x** = a;

вот это объявление надо убрать, т.е. будет

```
x = a;
```

А то конструктор у тебя вообще своей функции не выполнял.

Т.е. было:

```
Calculate(int a, int b) {
    int x = a;
    int y = b;
}
```

стало:

```
Calculate(int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!